# Receiving MQMessage using JMSListener results in a String of comma separated integers

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a project that is using a `JMSListener` to read messages off of a WebsphereMQ queue. One of my requirements for this is to connect to multiple queues and put them to the "main" queue the `JMSListener` is wired up to. To do this I loop through a list of queues and use IBM's MQ packages to do the browsing from the queue in the loop and then the writing to the "main" queue. This is my read and write methods (Nothing wrong with them, just including for sake of information):

```
public String readFromErrorQueue(MyErrorQueue errorQueue,
            MQGetMessageOptions getMsgOpts) throws MQException, IOException {
        MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
        String message = "";
        errorQueue.getQueue().get(msg, getMsgOpts);
        message = msg.readStringOfCharLength(msg.getMessageLength());
        return message;
    }

    public void writeToHoldQueue(String message) throws IOException,
            MQException {
        MQMessage mqMessage = new MQMessage();
        mqMessage.writeString(message);
        holdQueue.getQueue().put(mqMessage, putMsgOpts);
    }
```

And the main JMSListener is in the form:

```
@JmsListener(id ="mainQueue", destination = "${mq.queueName}")
    public void processOrder(String message) throws Exception {...}
```

Now to my predicament. When my `JMSListener` receives the message it is in the form `"98, 122, 34, 190, ... , N"` instead of being a string of actual words. Just to note, those values I put are arbitrary, as I don't know if the integers can be deciphered to a meaningful message and HIPPA is pretty strict about that stuff... Anyways, the message is supposed to be a HL7 or XML message.

A few things to note in my debugging; I can see the HL7/XML message as it is supposed to be when I'm looping through the queue, so as I browse them in they look fine. Before I write them to the "main" queue they look fine. And when they are on the "main" queue, if I pop open MQ Explorer and look at the content of the messages that are currently on the queue they look fine. And finally to note, if I put a test message on the queue from MQ Explorer the `JMSListener` picks it up just fine.

So this leads me to believe the problem lies with how MQ puts messages on the queue with java code, and how the `JMSListener` takes them off. And the only thing I can think of is that my `writeToHoldQueue` puts the message on as a MQMessage, where as my `JMSListener` is wanting to read a String.

So are my suspicions correct, what's going on here? Why do I get a long string of seemingly random comma separated integers instead of an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a little ironic. Turns out there was something wrong with my `writeToHoldQueue()`. After digging (and honestly using this post as a little rubber ducky), I realized that I have the ability to define the `MQMessage` format. So basically all of my problems were solved with this one little line... `mqMessage.format = MQConstants.MQFMT_STRING;`. Now my listener is picking up non-garbled, proper strings like I need. So my writer now looks like:

```
public void writeToHoldQueue(String message) throws IOException,
            MQException {
        MQMessage mqMessage = new MQMessage();
        mqMessage.format = MQConstants.MQFMT_STRING;
        mqMessage.messageType = MQConstants.MQMT_DATAGRAM;

        mqMessage.writeString(message);
        holdQueue.getQueue().put(mqMessage, putMsgOpts);
    }
```

If anyone else runs across this I found these two sorces helpful in writing up my read and write: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030840_.htm

and
https://endrasenn.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/readwrite-to-ibm-mq-sample-java-code/

Comment: If you control the encoding at both endpoints, `MQFMT_STRING` is fine for XML, but be careful if you're dealing with `iso_1` or `cp1252`, they are likely to get mangled by the  `utf-8` encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm actually not familiar with those two terms, I'll look into it.